# One line input. Ints and not ints

Tags: c++, input

i am new at c++, i've coded before it just on python, so, this is a new world for me and sorry if this question is obvious. 
Today, i've tried to write my first codeforces on c++, and i get stucked. I have one line of ints, like

```
10, 10, 10, 13, 1341, 134, 134, 184431
```

with the lengts m. In this particular example, m=8. How can I read them and save to my array/vector? 
And there is an another question, if i have non-standart input, for example, n and m symbols in( *, #) like

```
####
****
#*#*
```

There is n=3, m=4. If i want to represent # like 1 and * like 0, and save it in may vector of vectors, how can i do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question:

```
int m;
std::cin >> m;

std::vector<int> v(m);
for (auto i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    std::cin >> v[i];
```

And the second:

```
int n, m;
std::cin >> n >> m;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(m));
std::string line;

for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> line;
    for (auto j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        if (line[j] == '#')
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
        else
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what's about not using c++11?

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said... The only C++11 you'll find there is `auto`, using `int` is the same.

Comment: Just use scanf() in replace of cin

Comment: @yousuf `scanf()` is a function made for **C**. In **C++**, you can use `cin`. And it doesn't matter if we're talking about C++11 or the older version, all versions accept `cin`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how to do first question with numbers with enters, it means like(1
                      2
                      3) and etc.